# Help on computing some property value of a binary tree.

Tags: trees, binary

I am trying to compute some properties of a binary tree, but I cant find its formula. What I did to get the initial value is, I draw the binary tree on paper and manually count the nodes, pairs, etc. But I was not able to create formula out of it. The only thing I got is the `number of nodes per level`.

```
+-------+-------+----------------------+---------------+-----------------------+
| Index | Level | # of nodes per level | maximum nodes | total leaf nodes pair |
+-------+-------+----------------------+---------------+-----------------------+
|     0 |     1 |                    1 |             1 |                     0 |
|     1 |     2 |                    2 |             3 |                     1 |
|     2 |     3 |                    4 |             7 |                     5 |
|     3 |     4 |                    8 |            15 |                    17 |
|     4 |     5 |                   16 |            31 |                    49 |
|     5 |     6 |                   32 |       unknown |               unknown |
+-------+-------+----------------------+---------------+-----------------------+
```

The `maximum nodes` is the overall total count of nodes.

The `total leaf nodes pair` is the sum of all the node leaf pairs.

For example, the Tree has 3 levels, then the first node on level 1, will got 3 leaf pairs.

Then two nodes on level 2, will get 1 pair each, while 4 nodes on level 3 while got zero pairs each.
Then total of it overall is 5.

What would be the formula for computing the `maximum nodes` and `total leaf nodes pair`?

**EDIT**
Additional info about the `total leaf nodes pair`.

*(should be a perfect/complete binary tree)*

- If a parent node has 3 child node on left and has 3 child node on the right, then its total leaf node is 3.
- Sum all the pairs of every node, then that will be the `total leaf nodes pair` of the tree.
- Example, lets say we only got 2 levels. The first level will got 1 child on left and 1 child on right, so the very first node will have 1 pair. While the nodes on 2nd level will got none because they are no more nodes below them. Then the `total leaf nodes pair` will be only 1.
- Another example, lets assume we got 4 levels

  - Because the total level is 4, then the very first node will have 7 pairs. 7 pairs because, on complete binary it will have 7 child nodes in left and right.
  - Then the next 2 nodes on level 2, will got 3 pairs each. 3 pairs each because, on complete binary they will have 3 child nodes in left and right. With the total of 6.
  - While the 4 nodes on level 3, will got 1 pair each. 1 pairs because they only have 1 pairs of child nodes each. With the total of 4.
  - And the last 8 nodes on level 4 will got nothing because they don't have child nodes. zero because, this is the last level and there is no more nodes below.
  - In total, there is 17 `total leaf nodes pair`

***Edit with solution***

I tried to solve it by my self and come up with this solution.
Pardon I cant be sure if this is the right way to write this solution.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{m}\sum_{x=m-1}^0(2^x)(2^{n-1}-1)$$

***Request to reopen this question***

I got my answer, but @GarethMa solution is much better.

Can I request this question to re-open, so than @GarethMa can post its solution.

**P.S.**

@GerryMyerson posted link, also solve the second `total leaf nodes pair` problem, the only difference is it at starting $$index = 0$$ while @GarethMa answer is starting on $$index=1$$

Thank you.

Comment: can you explain the "leaf node pair" more in depth? Also, maximum nodes is always $2^x-1$ where x is the level, which is achieved when every level is complete (Complete binary tree)

Comment: @GarethMa I added more info, sorry take to long to reply, the computation on  `total leaf nodes pair` is incorrect. But I already fix it, the value should be 17 and 49, for level 4 and 5 respectively.

Comment: ??? I was almost done with the answer. What's unclear about this question? How do i vote to open it again help i wasted like 20 minutes. It looks clear to me

Comment: anyways this is my answer :) https://pastebin.com/ZhGfBaGw

Comment: Is http://oeis.org/A000337 what you're looking for?

Comment: @GerryMyerson indeed, that solve the second problem

Comment: @GarethMa I'm sorry the question got closed, I hope they will reopen it, I edited the quetion to put more details. BTW Thank you so much, your answer is what I need. If they will reopen it, post your answer and I will accept it. Once again thank you.

Comment: requesting to reopen takes 3000 rep:((

Comment: @GarethMa based on this https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078 any edited question will be queue for a review.

Comment: @GarethMa you may post it now, please. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a $n$ level complete binary tree:

Claim: there are $2^n-1$ nodes

Proof: In the complete binary tree, the root level (level $1$) has only 1 node. Level $2$ will have 2 nodes, each a direct child from the root. Level $3$ will have 4 nodes, each a direct child of the previous level. All the way until level $n$ has $2^{n-1}$ nodes.

Total amount of nodes = $1 + 2 + 4 + \cdots + 2^{n-1} = 2^n - 1$

~~

Claim: there are $(n-2)2^{n-1}+1$ leaf nodes pair.

Proof: This time we can work backwards. We can consider each node in each level, and sum up the contribution as following:

$$\textrm{LN Pair} = \sum_{l=1}^n (\textrm{number of nodes in level } n)(\textrm{leaf node pair of node in level } n) = \sum_{l=1}^n (2^{l-1})(f_n(l))$$

Let's look at a numerical example to figure out what $f_n(l)$ is. Let's look at $n=4$, $l=2$. Each node in $l=2$ has 3 children in subtree, and thus $f_n(l)=f_4(2)=3$. It shouldn't be hard to see that $f_n(l)=\textrm{number of nodes in complete binary tree with height } (n-l) = 2^{n-l}-1$

$\therefore$ required sum is $$\sum_{l=1}^n(2^{l-1})(2^{n-l}-1)=\sum_{l=1}^n 2^{n-1}-2^{l-1}=n2^{n-1}-(2^n-1)=(n-2)2^{n-1}+1$$ as desired! :)
[image]